# Idea 12/Haxe2.10(win): why do I get AssertionError: Wrong node when I try to build a project?

Tags: exception, intellij-idea, haxe

My OS is `Win7 64 Enterprise`.

I've just installed `idea12 (ultimate)`, added `Haxe plugin (0.5.6)`, installed `haxe sdk 2.10win`, also tried using 2.09win that comes with fdt.

When I try to build a project with Idea, I get following exception:

```
Internal error: (java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException) java.lang.AssertionError: Wrong node: [null]
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.AssertionError: Wrong node: [null]
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerGet(FutureTask.java:252)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.get(FutureTask.java:111)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.a(JpsProjectLoader.java:231)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.a(JpsProjectLoader.java:105)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.loadProject(JpsProjectLoader.java:81)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.JpsModelLoaderImpl.loadModel(JpsModelLoaderImpl.java:41)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildRunner.load(BuildRunner.java:60)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.runBuild(BuildSession.java:169)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildSession.run(BuildSession.java:94)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.cmdline.BuildMain$MyMessageHandler$1.run(BuildMain.java:105)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.service.impl.SharedThreadPoolImpl$1.run(SharedThreadPoolImpl.java:26)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: java.lang.AssertionError: Wrong node: [null]
    at com.intellij.util.xmlb.BeanBinding._deserializeInto(BeanBinding.java:133)
    at com.intellij.util.xmlb.BeanBinding.deserialize(BeanBinding.java:120)
    at com.intellij.util.xmlb.XmlSerializer.deserialize(XmlSerializer.java:58)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.haxe.model.module.JpsHaxeModuleType$1.loadProperties(JpsHaxeModuleType.java:26)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.haxe.model.module.JpsHaxeModuleType$1.loadProperties(JpsHaxeModuleType.java:23)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.a(JpsProjectLoader.java:294)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.a(JpsProjectLoader.java:255)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader.access$000(JpsProjectLoader.java:44)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader$2.call(JpsProjectLoader.java:225)
    at org.jetbrains.jps.model.serialization.JpsProjectLoader$2.call(JpsProjectLoader.java:222)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:35)
    ... 7 more
```

This issue can't be in Haxe sdk as it compiles project fine under fdt (however, sdk-based autocomplete is not working, but I think it is not related to idea problem). Other project types (like java) are working fine with idea.

So, what shall I try to solve this issue? What does that exception mean?

*Update*: Installed `idea 12.01` on `WIN7 32 Professional`, created new project - same exception happens. So, I conclude that this issue is not related to 32/64 bit OS or Java. This issue is not specific to idea version 12.00.

May be it is important that new project created by idea contains neither `.hx` classes, nor any build configuration files(like `.hxml`). I tried to create .hx main class and .hxml build for it, but idea still does not build project.

Changing run configuration to one of those files or to .swf result(built manually) or to cmd does not help(`run` option still not available).

I also tried to build with ant task, and it succeeded, but idea still can't build a project when I choose this option from menu.

Comment: It may be caused by the corrupted project file, try to create the new project.

Answer (score 2):

The problem will be fixed in IDEA 12.0.2, thank you for reporting. As a workaround you can switch off 'Use external build' option in File | Settings | Compiler.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot reproduce your error. Please try the usual reinstall, remove/add the Haxe SDK again, Invalidate Cache and restart (from the file menu).

If you can reproduce this problem with a fresh install, the best place for Idea support is their forum or create a new issue on their tracker http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA?p=0&q=haxe

They have been very helpful to me in the past.

Comment: I've just looked in their tracker and found lots of bugs that don't exactly equal to my issue, but cause similar inability to run or build a project. Can you provide more details about your installation? How did you act to avoid this and related issues?

Comment: I just have the same versions you describe on a windows 64 system. Maybe you should try to reinstall java?

Comment: what java version do you use? Maybe I shall use old java 1.6?